# Dataweave - Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, root-element

I have an Application/Java ArrayList. That contains XML elements in String format.
I want to add to a main/root node with Dataweave 2:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
shops: write(vars.shop, "application/xml")
```

But it returns:

```
Caused by:
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document)
```

How can I solved that? I tried with application/java but still failing, the problem is into the write() method trying to transform the array to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the vars.shop has? Most commonly for xml building you need to use the dynamic object feature.

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns ns0 http://example/catalog/2002-13-23
var shops = ["data example","data example2","data example123","data example345","data example56"]
---
{
    ns0#shops @("shops-id": "demo"): {
        (shops map (shopName) -> {
            ns0#shop: shopName     
        })
    }
}
```

This script outputs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns0:shops xmlns:ns0="http://example/catalog/2002-13-23" shops-id="demo">
  <ns0:shop>data example</ns0:shop>
  <ns0:shop>data example2</ns0:shop>
  <ns0:shop>data example123</ns0:shop>
  <ns0:shop>data example345</ns0:shop>
  <ns0:shop>data example56</ns0:shop>
</ns0:shops>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
---
shops: read(vars.shop, "application/xml")
```

Comment: It also fail: `- Expecting Type: `String`, but got: `Array<Nothing>`.
- Expecting Type: `Binary`, but got: `Array<Nothing>`.`